# Save a file in R

Tags: r

I have been trying to save a dataframe into csv format in r. It has 22 variables with in various formats. Am finding a solution to save a file in csv.

```
write.csv(newdata,file = "MyDataNew.csv")
```

> Error in write.table(newdata, file = "MyDataNew.csv", col.names = NA,  : 
>    unimplemented type 'list' in 'EncodeElement'

I would like the file to be saved in csv format.

Comment: Looks like `newdata` may be a tibble containing a list column - the output from `str(newdata)` would be helpful. List columns can't be written to CSV . Perhaps you can `unnest()` first.

Comment: Dataset contains 22 variables with multiple classes. The output of str(newdata) cannot be pasted here as it is too long. It would be great if you could tell the exact code for  unnest()?

Comment: You could try `write.csv(unnest(newdata), file = "MyDataNew.csv")`. That assumes only one list column. You'll need `library(tidyr)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It worked out for me after 2 days long struggle!

Answer (score 1):

This will probably be fixed by:

```
write.csv(as.data.frame(newdata),file = "MyDataNew.csv")
```

Comment: This will generate exactly the same error. Try it: `tibble(a = 1:4, b = list(1:4)) %>% as.data.frame() %>% write.csv("out.csv")`

Comment: Can you please explain the value of a and b?

Comment: It's just an example tibble with a list column, the values don't matter.

Comment: I still could not able to get it. My dataframe has 22 variables with multiple class functions like factor, character, posticx etc.